# /entitydata command + armor stands . How do I do it properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make armor stand animations. My original idea which looked messy was to kill a configured armor stand and summon an armor stand with different hand positions for example. Instead, I thought it would look cleaner by using the `/entitydata` tag to alter its

```
RightArm:[2f,0f,0f]
```

tag, and then using

```
execute @e[name=TS-19] ~ ~ ~ /tp ~0.05 ~ ~
```

The entity data does not work. Might this be because I have to print the whole body rotation (e.g adding all of the limbs rotations) for it to work?

Why won't this work, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was suspicious of this and only logical. You have to include the entire Pose: tag. My command ended up like this

```
/entitydata @e[name=TS-19] {Pose:{Body:[4f,0f,0f],Head:[4f,0f,0f],LeftLeg:[7f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[2f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[2f,0f,0f],RightArm:[100f,0f,0f]}}
```